# Can I offset the touch points in Objective C?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Is it possible to offset UITouch points? I am using the touches methods shown below. I want to offset the touch points by some number so that a user will see where the touch will start and draw. If I am trying to draw within lines, I want to see above my fingertip, much like we do with pens and pencils.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    
    
    // add the first touch
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    
    previousPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
  
    // init the bezier path
    self.currentTool = [self toolWithCurrentSettings];
    self.currentTool.lineWidth = self.lineWidth;
    self.currentTool.lineColor = self.lineColor;
    self.currentTool.lineAlpha = self.lineAlpha;
    
    [self.currentTool setInitialPoint:currentPoint];
...

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    
    // save all the touches in the path
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    
    //currentPoint.y += 40;
     CGRect bounds = [(DrawingPenTool*)self.currentTool addPathPreviousPoint:previousPoint2 withPreviousPoint:previousPoint1 withCurrentPoint:currentPoint];

        CGRect drawBox = bounds;
        drawBox.origin.x -= self.lineWidth * 2.0;
        drawBox.origin.y -= self.lineWidth * 2.0;
        drawBox.size.width += self.lineWidth * 4.0;
        drawBox.size.height += self.lineWidth * 4.0;
        
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:drawBox];    
        [self.currentTool moveFromPoint:previousPoint1 toPoint:currentPoint];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    
      CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
      [self.currentTool setInitialPoint:point];
    
     
        }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIEvent [`predictedTouches`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uievent/1613814-predictedtouches) and UITouch [`estimatedProperties`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitouch/1618130-estimatedproperties) to learn where the *next* touch will probably be. In this way you can keep drawing "ahead" of the user. That is exactly what this feature is for.

Comment: Watch a "touch" video from WWDC 2015 or 2016 to learn more about this. Drawing apps are exactly the target audience for these videos.

Comment: Thanks @matt. Off to watch a video or 2

Comment: can I use estimatedProperties even if I'm not using an Apple Pencil?

Comment: You can use UIEvent `predictedTouches`. I'll add that to my answer!